# Alfresco duplicated node name exception

Tags: javascript, alfresco

I'm trying to change the name of all documents(cm:name) and the documentTypeName (it works ok) but when i´m trying to change the cm:name it throws duplicate nodename exception. All this is for create a rule in alfresco. Sorry for my english

```
 var documentText = null;
    var query = "@pa\\:documentTypeId:" + document.properties["paList:id"];
    var extenson= null;
    var resultSet = search.luceneSearch(query);
    documentText = resultSet[0].properties['pa:documentType'];

    if(resultSet.length>0){
        query = "@pa\\:documentTypeId:" + document.properties["paList:id"] + " AND " + "@pa\\:documentType:" + documentText;
        response = search.luceneSearch(query);
        for(i=0;i<resultSet.length;i++){
            extension = (resultSet[i].properties['cm:name'].substring(resultSet[i].properties['cm:name'].lastIndexOf(".")));

            response[i].properties['cm:name'] = response[i].properties['pa:documentType'] + extension;

            response[i].properties['pa:documentType'] = document.properties["paList:description"];
            response[i].save();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you please write the correct name of the exception? Just to be sure that we understand what exception is.

Comment: There is something difficult to understand in your code. You execute a first lucene search and set the variable "resultSet". In case you find more than one result, you execute another lucene search with an additional constraint and store the result in the variable "response" Then you loop on resultSet, but you use the same index "i" to access both "resultSet" and "response". Isn't possible that "response" containes less results than resultSet?

Comment: Hi, Marco thanks for you response, so the exact name of exception is: .DuplicateChildNodeNameException: Duplicate child name not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

```
response[i].properties['cm:name'] = response[i].properties['pa:documentType'] + extension;
```

Looks like you are renaming the nodes so they start with document type and then the file extension.

So if you have filea.doc and fileb.doc in the same folder and the had the same pa:documentType (lets say worddoc), they would both be called worddoc.doc
This will give you a DuplicateChildNodeNameException, because 2 files with the samen name is impossible.